# Dynamic condition in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have the following condition:

```
if "FIX_STRING 0,0,DYNAMIC_STRING" == "FIX_STRING #{integer_from_0_to_5},#{integer_from_0_to_5},#{DYNAMIC_STRING}"
  true
else
  false
end
```

How to make it dynamically like this?

```
if "FIX_STRING 0,0,DYNAMIC_STRING" == "FIX_STRING #{/0|1|2|3|4|5/},#{/0|1|2|3|4|5/},#{/A|B|C|D/}"
  true
else
  false
end
```

Comment: really unclear what you're trying to do here. Maybe describing your goal in plain english would be better.

Comment: Are you looking for a regex like this: `if "FIX_STRING 0,0,DYNAMIC_STRING".match(/FIX_STRING [0-5],[0-5],[A-Z_]+/) then true else false end`? Does it have to match the whole DYNAMIC_STRING or uppercased chars from A to D only? Please ask your question more precisely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track here, but you've got a very peculiar coding style. The first thing to point out is that a comparison like `==` already returns a boolean value of `true` or `false`, there's no reason for the `if` which then returns exactly the same thing.

The second thing is that you're comparing a string to another string, so they have to match *exactly*. Close enough does not count. If you evaluate your other string you get a mess:

```
"FIX_STRING (?-mix:0|1|2|3|4|5),(?-mix:0|1|2|3|4|5),(?-mix:A|B|C|D)"
```

Finally, if you're trying to test a string versus a regular expression, you do this:

```
PATTERN = /\AFIX_STRING [0-5],[0-5],[A-D]\z/
```

You can test this sort of thing on [Rubular](http://rubular.com) to get it right. Here `[0-5]` means anything in that range. It's short-hand for what you had.

Then you can test arbitrary strings versus this pattern:

```
"FIX_STRING 3,4,D".match(PATTERN)
# => #<MatchData "FIX_STRING 3,4,D">
```

So that matched.

Newer versions of Ruby have a `match?` method that only tests matches, it doesn't return what matched, which you might want to make use of if you're running on 2.3 or later. It's faster than the plain `match` method, though that only really matters if you're doing a lot of matches inside loops.

Comment: Ruby 2.4 will introduce `Regexp#match?` which returns `true` or `false` and doesn't set global variables. But `match?` isn't available in 2.3 and I don't think there's a `String#match?` in 2.4.